# Using a Lambda expression to retrieve the first item in a child collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, lambda, poco

I'm currently writing a very basic Web API application and I have a case where I would like to retrieve the first item in a collection attached to a data entity.

As an example, let say I have the following POCO classes:

```
class Parent {
  int ParentId { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set;}
  string Description { get; set; }

  virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

class Child {
  int ChildId { get; set;}
  string Name {get; set;}

  int ParentId { get; set; }
  Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

Which show the one-many relationship between the two entities. Assume that the DbContext is not an issue and everything else is working fine. I would like to execute something along the lines of:

`DbContext.Parent.Include(d=>d.Children.Take(1)).ToList();`

In a nutshell, "give me all Parent records with the first entry of the Children collection"

However I can't get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what actually you want ? select first Parent element which contain First child ?

Comment: I'm after all Parent items with the one child record returned. Note: I'm not after all Parent items with Child record count == 1

Comment: Do you want all parents and first child of each parent ? Or you want All parents and Only One child object along with the all parents?

Comment: can you make clear "all Parent items with the one child record returned"

Comment: Based on documentation online what you have should work. When you say you can't get this to work, what do you mean. What results do you get with your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all parents along with first child of each parent, use this:

```
DbContext.Parent.Include(d => d.Children.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Or, if you want all parents along with only one child, you need to create one class say, ParentChild like this:

```
Public class ParentChild
{
    ICollection<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    Child OneChild {get;set;}        
}
```

Now fetch this object from DbContext like:

```
var obj= new ParentChild()
{
  Parents= DbContext.Parent.ToList(),
  Child= DbContext.Child.FirstOrDefault(),
}
```

And use this object obj in your application.

Comment: Thanks @manoj I realise I can construct a domain object, but I would like to know if a lambda method exists which can accommodate

Comment: Yes, Lambda methods will be available on any collection of objects.

Comment: Hey @Matthew, If my answer helped you, please accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: Hi @manoj, Thanks for your response. This is not what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the DbContext is not an issue and everything else is working fine.
You would probably need to create a new projection to achieve what you want.

```
var projection = DbContext.Parent.Include(p => p.Children).Select(p => new {
    ParentId = p.ParentId,
    Name = p.Name,
    Description = p.Description,
    Child= p.Children.FirstOrDefault()
};
```

Otherwise making changes to the returned parent to return with only the first child could cause unwanted issues if a save was to be made on the db context.

You could however do this...

```
var projection = DbContext.Parent.Include(p => p.Children).Select(p => new Parent {
    ParentId = p.ParentId,
    Name = p.Name,
    Description = p.Description,
    Children = p.Children.Take(1).ToList()
};
```

..which creates a new object that is not attached to the context

Comment: This is similar to my first go, I'm just wondering if there is a better way

Comment: @MatthewMerryfull I think I have it.  `DbContext.Parent.Include(d=>d.Children.Take(1).ToList()).ToList();`. Children is `ICollection`, I don't believe `Take` returns `ICollectoion`. Try it and let me know. I'll update my answer.